# What happens when Data.Vector.unfoldr doesn't fuse?

Tags: arrays, haskell

Suppose I create a `Vector` using `unfoldr`, as opposed to `unfoldrN`, and it *doesn't* fuse, so the vector actually needs to be created. How does the system decide how large to make it? I haven't been able to find anything about this in the documentation. The source code shows that it calls `unstream`, which has a lot of complicated code I can't make head or tail of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not entirely sure, but I chased the source code from `unfoldr` until `Data.Vector.Generic.Mutable.unstream`. Its documentation states:

> Create a new mutable vector and fill it with elements from the
>   'Stream'. The vector will grow exponentially if the maximum size of
>   the 'Stream' is unknown.

So, my guess is that it starts with a small size (like 10 or so) and starts filling the vector. As soon as the vector is full, it doubles its size (or makes its size 50% larger, or increment its size by some other ratio) and copies the old elements into the new vector. Exponential growth ensures that if you fill the vector with n elements you will do at most O(log(n)) copies, hence the overall complexity will be O(n log(n)), which is "close enough" to linear time.

The actual ratio seems to be 2, as per the `enlarge_delta` function, which just returns `max 1 (length v)`, which is passed to `grow` which adds that many elements to the vector.

---

As [Carl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/383200/carl) notes, exponential copying is O(n), not only O(n log(n)). Indeed, using ratio=2, the number of copied elements would be (minus some rounding) 2^0+2^1+...+2^(log(n)) = 2^(log(n)+1)-1 = 2n-1, hence O(n).

Comment: Actually, exponential copying is O(n) - it just has higher constant factors than knowing the size in advance.

Comment: I must have been very close to that in the source, but I didn't quite get there. Whoops! Thanks a lot.

Comment: O(n log(n)) is more than O(n), so the "just" seems kinda off.

Comment: @Cubic replaced it with "only", as in not only <= n log n but also <= n (up to some constant factor).